# Intel integrated graphics 4000 with AMD Radeon HD 6850

Tags: graphics-card, intel-core-i7, integrated-graphics

I upgraded my computer processor recently to Intel I7 3770K which is a great processor but I was wondering if the Intel HD 4000 could do teamwork with my AMD Radeon HD 6850?

I was also kind of worried if this setup could cause performance loss due the bad things I've heard about using multiple graphics cards.

**The big question is:**
*Can my integrated graphics card do teamwork with my primary graphics card?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not team up those 2 cards as such. Those two cards wont support **Crossfire**. And **no**, there wont be any performance loss. I assume that your OS will let you choose which one to use  for what kind of tasks. I would myself get rid off the Intel one since it's bad.

Comment: It's better to switch to `discrete` in BIOS. That cause no trouble.

Comment: Yeap. The Intel one isn't worth having around anyway.

Comment: I am running Windows 8 and CPU Z can identify both of those bad boys. What do i set to discrete?

Comment: Set the AMD one as your discrete one in the BIOS as recommended by "week".

Comment: Have a look at this link. This is how the procedure is done on Lenovo. But, my assumption is that even on different BIOS they wont change the general idea too drastically. http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/Graphics-driver-and-BIOS-setting-for-ThinkPad-T410s-systems-with/ta-p/243509