# Intel HD 4000 and ATI graphics using both possible?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intel integrated graphics 4000 with AMD Radeon HD 6850](https://superuser.com/questions/506119/intel-integrated-graphics-4000-with-amd-radeon-hd-6850)

I have Intel HD 4000 graphics with two DVI outputs on board. Is it possible to use it with PCI-Ex ATI graphic card at the same time? I know that Windows cannot handle ATI and nVidia at the same time.
My OS is Win8 and workstation is HP Elite 7500. I want to plug in 4 displays.

Answer (score 2):

Windows up to Win7 can not support two different video drivers at the same time (besides USB, but that's another story). Win8 supposedly can, so you should be able to mix Intel and AMD (there is no ATI anymore, hasn't been for a long time). Your onboard chipset may limit this.

Your best option would likely be to buy a card with 4 outputs, like the AMD FirePro™ 2460

Comment: Windows 7 can, officially. XP and Vista can't. [The Desktop Window Manager in Windows 7 also adds support for systems using multiple heterogeneous graphics cards from different vendors.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7#Desktop_Window_Manager)

Comment: Interesting; I've not seen that work, but it's probably one of those "MS gets it right on the 3rd version" things.

Comment: If your drivers aren't all fully Windows 7 compliant, it may not work. Some vendors (including Intel) had a lot of non-Windows-7 compliant drivers initially. If both devices support DirectX 11, then it will definitely work (since you can't support DX 11 without fully Win7-compliant drivers).

Comment: For my AMD X1650 there is only Vista driver and my video card isn't recognized under Windows 8 :(